# Embedding of a Rieman surface of genus one in $\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: riemann-surfaces

In Jost's Compact Riemann Surfaces, he proves that every compact Riemann surface of genus one can be embedded into $\mathbb{P}^2$. Moreover, he proves the image of the embedding is the zero set of a polynomial of the form $y^2=x^3+ax+b$. I'm fine with his proof up to this point, but then, he claims that the left-hand side has three distinct zeros without any proof. How can one show that these are indeed distinct?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is a classical fact about cubics of that form, which are called 'depressed.' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Three_real_roots

Comment: If it has a double root, then $x^3+ax+b = (x-\beta)(x-\alpha)^2$ and the curve becomes $v=u^2 +\beta-\alpha$  with the change of variable $x=v +\alpha, y = uv$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$  thus of genus $0$. @AlfredYerger